# Cross-compiling for OS X from Linux

Tags: linux, macos, cross-compiling, darwin

Is there an easy to use tool-chain to compile code for **Darwin (mac's OS)** from Linux?

For example, I would like to compile libpcap (or tcpdump) on a Linux machine and run in on my MAC. I've come across `osxcross` but it requires getting the Xcode SDK and such, has anyone tried this before ?

Thanks.

Comment: Based on my experience with Linux and OS X, there's no easy way to cross-compile for OS X from Linux. It would probably be easiest/best to buy an older, second hand Mac or Macbook and work from it. Also note there is a free and open source [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/), which attempts to provide the Cocoa framework.

Comment: @jww I'm creating already three different shared libraries (Linux 32, 64 and Windows), so I'd really prefer to be able to create the forth one as well.

Comment: You won't be able to do it without the Xcode SDK because you need the header files. For what you are trying to do you are probably better off using a cross build image https://github.com/multiarch/crossbuild

Comment: +1 to jww; however, even if that\`s not quite legal (or is it?), you might want to install Hackintosh on a VM like VirtualBox. That\`d make compiling for Mac a lot easier.

Comment: In my experience, the best solution is to avoid osxcross and use homebrew on a mac instead.

Comment: I don't  think its possible. If you want you can rent a mac online from websites like http://www.macincloud.com or http://www.xcodeclub.com.

Comment: Not an answer, but just so you know: `tcpdump` and `libpcap` come preinstalled on macOS.

Answer (score 6):

You should give [darling](https://github.com/darlinghq/darling) a spin.

Darling is:

> Darling is a runtime environment for OS X applications.

It's like [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) for Mac OS X. Although it is still relatively a small
project, you can already compile applications using Xcode using darling.

```
Darling [~]$ hdiutil attach Xcode_7.2.dmg
/Volumes/Xcode_7.2
Darling [~]$ cp -r /Volumes/Xcode_7.2/Xcode.app /Applications
Darling [~]$ export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
Darling [~]$ echo 'void main() { puts("Hello world"); }' > helloworld.c
Darling [~]$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang helloworld.c -o helloworld
Darling [~]$ ./helloworld
Hello world
```

I'm not sure a more complicated program will compile correctly and will work on Mac, but it's worth a try.

Alternatively, you can run Mac OS X on a Virtualbox inside Linux, and then transfer the compiled files to the destination machine.

Comment: The license agreement of Mac OS (at least current versions) prohibits its being run on non-Apple hardware, even if it's technically possible to do so.

Comment: Quoting the FAQ at https://www.darlinghq.org/:
`**Does it violate Apple's EULA?**
No! We only directly use those parts of Darwin that are released as fully free software.`
I take from that statement that Darling doesn't conflict with the license agreement. But I'm not a lawyer.